# Meta Tag: [high-intensity]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup, meta-tags

I just did some retagging and stumbled over [high-intensity](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-intensity). It is a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and should be removed:

> The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).
>
> Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. These are tags that don’t say anything by themselves – you can’t tell what the question is about unless they’re paired with some other tag (or several of them). These tags are a problem because people don’t realize this and will often use that as the question’s only tag.

---

I just introduced [interval-training](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interval-training) and we already have [hiit](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiit). [high-intensity](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-intensity) is just a qualifier, is ambiguous and could be used for nearly everything (and currently is).

Comment: And I think [tag:hiit] needs a synonym, as many people might not look for that abbreviation.